# Renaming multiple directory names with regex using powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, directory

I got stuck at some point.
Assuming following directory:

```
d:\example
             0 test1_123.txt
<DIR>          test1_123_abc0
             0 test2.txt
<DIR>          test2_123
<DIR>          test3_123_abc1
<DIR>          test4_test0_abc0
```

I want now to remove the postfix using regex '_abc*' of all directory names. I tried the following:

```
Get-ChildItem d:\example\ -Directory | foreach { rename-item $_ $_ -replace '_abc.' }
```

Does anybody know whats wrong here and can share the solution?

Comment: Try `Get-ChildItem 'd:\example\' -Recurse -Filter *_abc* | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '_abc\d*$', ''}`

Comment: what do you think this >>> `{ rename-item $_ $_ -replace '_abc.' }` <<< means? have you tested it? [*grin*] those two `$_` items look oh-so-very-wrong ...

Comment: also, how do you want to handle the dupe dir names when truncating one makes it a dupe of another?

Answer (score 1):

here's one solution to the problem ... [*grin*]

what it does ...

- creates some files & dirs to test with
  when ready to do this for real, just remove the entire `#region/#endregion` block.
- sets the target dir, dir filter, and regex remove pattern
  if you want to also remove `_abc` without any digits at the end, replace the `+`  [one or more] with an `*` [zero or more].
- grabs the list of matching dirs
- iterates thru that list
- renames the dir by stripping off the *ending* that matches the regex

please note that this DOES NOT handle name collisions. if you run this code twice you WILL see such when `test5_abc666` gets renamed to `test5` ... and a dir with that name already exists. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
#region >>> make some test files & dirs
@(
'test1_123.txt'
'test2.txt'
'test3_abc9.log'
) | ForEach-Object {
    $Null = New-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Name $_ -ItemType File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
@(
'test1_123_abc0'
'test2_123'
'test3_123_abc1'
'test4_test0_abc0'
'test5_abc666'
) | ForEach-Object {
    $Null = New-Item -Path $env:TEMP -Name $_ -ItemType Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
#endregion >>> make some test files & dirs

$TargetDir = $env:TEMP
$Filter = '*_abc*'
$Regex_ThingToRemove = '_abc\d+$'

$DirList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TargetDir -Directory -Filter $Filter
foreach ($DL_Item in $DirList)
    {
    Rename-Item -LiteralPath $DL_Item.FullName -NewName ($DL_Item.Name -replace $Regex_ThingToRemove)
    }
```